# Which library to use when trying to creating realtime pie chart using Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to creating an updating pie chart using Firebase? Something kind of like http://bl.ocks.org/d/1346410/? What library could I use?

Answer (score 4):

I've had great luck with [Highcharts and Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com). Here is an example of a [chart updating in real time](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update).

The idea is pretty straightforward:

- monitor Firebase for changes: `ref.on('value|child_added', ... )`
- call [Series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series).setData() to modify the data (probably what you want for a pie)
- or call Series.addPoint() to add new points to the data

Comment: Hi Kato, thanks! This is a really great solution for line graphs. Do you know if there is anything like this for pie/circle graphs?

Comment: They have [pie charts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) as well; very nice ones; they also work with the same series methods for resize/append/et al.